# Wordpress is already installed

Tags: installation

I installed WP however I don't remember the login and password. So I need to do the configuration again where I set the email and password. However when I acesss that page:

```
http://localhost:80/wp-admin/install.php
```

It shows a message saying that Wordpress is already installed: "You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first.

Do you know what is necessary to do to do the initial configuration again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is already clear "clear your old database". Alternatively you could update the credentials in the database directly (there are tutorials how to do this online).

Comment: Thanks, but clearing all database tables is not fixing the issue.

Comment: Try deleting all tables in the DB and maybe even the wp-config.php

Comment: unless you want to erase your site and start your site completely from scratch the `install.php` URL is not the solution you were hoping for. Use the forgotten password link on the login page to recover your account, or modify the password via the database/WP CLI/emergency.php(from wp.org).

Comment: If I remove the wp-config file I get a lot of errors. The issue is that I don't remember the password and it seems that I typed the email wrongly because to recover the password it says that the email doesn't exist. That file to modify the password is inside a wp-cli directory? Im not finding that directory on the project folder.

Comment: Go into the DB table for users and replace the email address with the correct one that you have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the username in the database and change the password easily. You do not need to reinstall wordpress.
If you need to reconfigure, there are several ways:

1. Delete wp-config.php and htaccess files and re run install
2. Delete the information in the database and reconfigure it

But if you want an easy way to find your username as well as change your password, you can do the following:
Just go to phpMyAdmin and find the ** wp_users ** table and click on it
You will now see the rows in your WordPress user table. Continue and click the edit button next to the username whose password you want to change.
Now delete the value in the user_pass field and replace it with your new password. Below the function column, select MD5 from the drop-down menu and then click the Go button at the bottom of the form.
Just as easily! You have successfully changed your WordPress password.